# How to get intersection of bag and tuple in Pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I have a bag like this (url:chararray mal:float) and like this (url:chararray links:chararray).
I want to parse the links field and intersect the bag with parsed links:

```
src = LOAD 'hbase://$collection' USING 

org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('info:url anchors:links', '-loadKey true') AS (id:bytearray, url:chararray, links:chararray);
mals = LOAD '/tmp/prepare' as (url:chararray, mal:float);

urls = FILTER src BY (links IS NOT null);

urls2 = FOREACH urls GENERATE TOKENIZE(links, '\t') as links, id, url;
processed = FOREACH urls2 {
    grouped = COGROUP links BY $0, mals BY url;
    intersected = FILTER grouped BY NOT IsEmpty(urls) AND NOT IsEmpty(links4);
    weights = FOREACH intersected GENERATE mal;
    GENERATE id, AVG(weights) as mal;
};
```

This code isn't working: parser fails with:

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <file ./Rank.pig, line 11, column 19>  [query, statement, foreach_statement, foreach_complex_statement, foreach_clause_complex, foreach_plan_complex, nested_blk, nested_command_list, nested_command, expr, add_expr, multi_expr, cast_expr, unary_expr, expr_eval, var_expr, projectable_expr, func_eval, recoverFromMismatchedToken] mismatched input 'links' expecting LEFT_PAREN
```

I'm using Pig 0.11.0.

As far as I understand links is tuple, and mals is bag, so they cannot be cogrouped. How can I create a bag with links to do cogroup?

UPD:
Example dataset:

```
/tmp/prepare: 
http://1 1.0
http://2 0.9
http://3 0.8
http://4 0.0

HBase:
id: ID
url: http://4
links: http://1 http://2 http://3
```

As output:

```
{(id: ID, mal: 0.9)}
```

Comment: You have `grouped = COGROUP links BY $0, mals BY url;` but there is no relation named `links` in the previous steps.  Also, you are `COGROUP`ing by `$0` and `url`?  This doesn't make sense.  It is hard to tell though where your problem is w/o an example snippet of your original relation.

Comment: May be I don't understand correctly the code, but it seems to me:
1) links is a relation generated by tokenize
2) I'm cogrouping in relation links by zeroth unnamed field (it is a link/url) and by field url in mals
Seems correct to me.

Comment: The relation generated by `TOKENIZE` is `urls2` with "columns" `links`, `id`, and `url`.

Comment: links as far as I understand is a bag inside of urls2 and I'm trying to work with it

Comment: Yes you are correct I was miss reading your code.  I always write the unaltered variables first so it would be `foreach urls generate id, url, TOKENIZE(links, '\t')`

Comment: Either way, there is still no relation named `links`

Comment: But if you edit your question and provide an example dataset and what you want the output to be I could help you get the answer.